# File completion priorities in ZSH

Tags: linux, zsh, zsh-completion

I have a shell pattern that marks some files as "boring" namely backup files, `pyo` files, vim backups, autogenerated directories and the like. Let's call it `$BORING_STUFF`.

```sh
zstyle ':completion:*' file-patterns \ 
    '%p:globbed-items' \
    '*(^-/):regular-files' \
    '*(^-/):boring-files' \
    '.*(^-/):hidden-files' \
    '*(-/):regular-directories' \
    '*(-/):boring-directories' \
    '.*(-/):hidden-directories'
```

In this case, I have the scope of each group also constrained by applicable `ignore-patterns`. (Such that `boring-files` contains only boring files and `regular-files` does not contain boring files)

I'd like bold items to always show up, and other items only show up if there are no other matches. (Aka. `touch <tab>` will show regular directories and regular files but not hidden files, while `touch .<tab>` will show hidden files.)

- **globbed items**
- directories

  - **regular directories**
  - boring directories
  - hidden directories
- files

  - **regular files**
  - boring files
  - hidden files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go.

```sh
setopt extended_glob
zstyle ':completion:*' file-patterns \
  "^($BORING_FILES|.*)(-/):directories:normal\ directories %p~($BORING_FILES|.*)(^-/):globbed-files:normal\ files" \
  "^($BORING_FILES|.*)(^-/):noglob-files:noglob\ files" \
  ".*~($BORING_FILES)(^-/):hidden-files:hidden\ files .*~($BORING_FILES)(-/):hidden-directories:hidden\ directories" \
  "($BORING_FILES)(^-/):boring-files:boring\ files ($BORING_FILES)(-/):boring-directories:boring\ directories" \

zstyle ':completion:*' group-order \
  builtins expansions aliases functions commands globbed-files \
  directories hidden-files hidden-directories \
  boring-files boring-directories keywords viewable
```